# In "boot" function in R, value of t0 is not matching the mean of the t

Tags: r

I'm writing a simple function to estimate the value of a statistic using ratio estimator and the dataset "iris". Here is my code:

```
library(boot)
rat=function(data,index) 
{
  X=data[index,1]
  Y=data[index,2]
  return(mean(Y)/mean(X)*Xbar)
}
Xbar=mean(iris$Sepal.Length)
N=nrow(iris)
n=0.7*N
samp<-sample(1:N,n,replace = F)
iris_samp<-iris[samp,]
output<-boot(iris_samp,rat,R=1000)
mean(output$t)
output$t0
```

The result I obtained was:

```
> mean(output$t)
[1] 3.057975
> output$t0
[1] 3.061799
```

I was under the impression that t0 is just the mean of t, i.e. the estimates from each sample. However, the two values clearly do not match here. Is  my coding incorrect or is my understanding wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `t0` is the estimate for the original dataset.  This should be close to the mean of the `t`'s depending on the bootstrap bias and the number of resamples but it won't be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

$t0 is coefficients when you run lm on the original data. $t are the bootstrapped values.

[here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61888174/r-interpretation-of-boot-output)